# Gracefully terminating socket thread

Tags: java, sockets, exception

Based on examples [here](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html), the simple socket server client will terminate when *.bye* is sent. The code below uses a thread-based approach to accept multiple clients but does not handle graceful handle client termination and will error out by repeating *null*.

The first example in the aforementioned link causes the client and server to exit. The server code below does not have a provision to disconnect when ".bye" is received. I would like the client to gracefully disconnect from the server. The server should close the connection when the ".bye" is received from the client. I believe this needs to be handled in the `System.out.println(streamIn.readUTF());` in the ChatServerThread?

**Question updated to reflect answer feedback, see history for original code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServerThread implements Runnable
//public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ChatServer      server   = null;
   private int             ID       = -1;
   private DataInputStream streamIn =  null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatServerThread(ChatServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {  server = _server;  socket = _socket;  ID = socket.getPort();
   }
   public void run() {
   try {
       handleClient();
   } catch( EOFException eof ) {
        System.out.println("Client closed the connection.");
   } catch( IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}

   public void handleClient() throws IOException {
      boolean done = false;
      try {
      System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      while (!done) {
        String nextCommand = streamIn.readUTF();
        if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {
           done = true;
        } else {
           System.out.println( nextCommand );
        }
     }
   } finally {
     streamIn.close();
     streamOut.close();
     socket.close();
   }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {
      streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStre
am()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutput
Stream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
      if (streamOut != null) streamOut.close();
   }
}
```

The first error is due to `implements Runnable`. The second I am not sure though `java.io.*` is imported so I am not sure why it's complaining.

```
ChatServer.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
         client.start();
               ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable client of type ChatServerThread
```

Comment: Where are you setting thread instance in ChatServer class to null? your code for accepting client connections serverSocket.accept() is in loop. You need to run the loop only fixed number of times which is equal to number of clients. In your case, your program will be blocked on serverSocket.accept() call. If you handle this case rest of thing should work.

Comment: @JProgrammer Original question clarified, I hope. Looking to gracefully disconnect the client after the server receives a statement that is matched `readUTF`. I should not have included the extraneous example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't shutdown a server because a client said bye.  That means any user could connect to your server and remotely shutdown without your control.  Shutting down the server is handled by the admin or owner of the server, and generally done by running a command on the server through an authenticated ssh session.  On unix/linux you might run:

```
service chatserver stop
```

That's another topic how to make that work, but just to give you a general overview of best practices.  Now if you want to shutdown a client when the conversation is over.  That makes more sense:

```
public class ChatServerThread implements Runnable {

    .......

    public void run() {
        try {
            handleClient();
        } catch( EOFException eof ) {
            System.out.println("Client closed the connection.");
        } catch( IOException ioe ) {
            ioe.printStacktrace();
        }
    }

    public void handleClient() throws IOException {
       boolean done = false;
       try {
          while(!done) {  
             String nextCommand = streamIn.readUTF();
             if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {
                done = true;
             } else {
                System.out.println( nextCommand );
             }
          }
       } finally {
          streamIn.close();
          streamOut.close();
          socket.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Then you can free up that thread to service the next client, or simply shut it down.  With DataInputStream you will get a EOFException when the client closes the socket without sending a ".bye".  So you can catch the EOFException before the IOException, and simply shutdown.

Notice I did not subclass Thread. Instead I implemented a Runnable which gives you more flexibility in the future should you want to create a Thread pool or something fancier.

Comment: I clarified the original question, I should not have included example I was referencing. Looking to disconnect the client in the `ChatServerThread`.

Comment: My answer then wouldn't change because that code is the server's thread loop for servicing a client.  I moved the try statement so it surrounds the while loop so if an exception is thrown it will end the conversation.  Normally, that's what you want to do when you get an exception from a socket's stream.  Plus EOFException should close the stream anyway.

Comment: Works great except for the `finally` portion that closes the streams and socket: `error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown streamIn.close();` Question code updated. When the client issues ".bye" clean disconnect occurs. If ctrl-C is used, _null_ entry shows up on server terminal. Is there a way to have the server output something useful when client disconnects?

Comment: So close() can throw an IOException so you'll have to handle those as well.  Typically I simply let all IOExceptions bubble up and out of my client loop method then catch them right at the borders of the Thread, log them, and let the thread either die or return to the thread pool.  IOExceptions, when dealing with streams from the socket, normally mean the client has become lost by either network errors, timeouts, terminations, or the client simply shutdown their side of the socket.  In all cases it means the conversation is over so clean up and move on.

Comment: That makes sense and sounds like an ideal solution. I have updated the question to include two errors I am receiving upon implementing the changes.

Comment: Astron, I think you have enough information to answer your question.  At this point I'm writing your code for you, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow.  You need to do some simple research in how to fix those issues you're having.  The first error was introduced when switching to using Runnable over Thread.  Research Threading and you can figure it out.  The other is a simple typo that could easily be filled in with just a little research.